# FFT and IFFT in LabVIEW using GPU toolkit

Tags: fft, labview

I am new to CUDA and FFT and as a first step I began with LabVIEW GPU toolkit. I have to use this toolkit due to batch processing of signals.

My issue concerns inverse FFT . To test FFT and inverse FFT I am generating a sine wave and passing it to the FFT function and then the spectrums to inverse FFT.

My setup is:

FFT :

Data is originally in double , it is prepared into complex single.
Array is 1024*1024 where each row is a sine wave with a specific frequency.

FFT type : CUFFT_C2C
Batch Size : 1024
FFT size : 1024

Inverse FFT :

Spectrums data type :  Complex Single.
Array size is 1024*1024 where each row is a sine wave with a specific frequency.

IFFT type : CUFFT_C2R
Batch Size : 1024
FFT size : 1024

Output spectrum from the FFT function is then passed onto inverse FFT, expecting to observe the same sine wave.

But I see something different, the first row of original sinewave and inverse FFT correspond. Rest of the signals don’t, they look weird.

PF images highlighting the issue :

[Signal 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBb7r.png)

[Signal 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA7qo.png)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1bC9.png)

Hopefully, somebody can help me with this issue

Have a nice day !

Comment: Does the fft function have a built in averaging? Perhaps that you need to force it to reset averaging every time so the lines are treated individually?

Comment: @EricJensen : Thank you for your input . The function does not have built in averaging . On my end I do not perform any averaging as well